# How to load data to HDFS (local HDInsight) programmatically?

Tags: c#, hadoop, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

Is there a way of loading data into my local HDFS cluster programmatically using c#?

I found a tutorial about loading data to Azure using C# code using the SDK but it requires blob storage and is not for a local cluster. Any workarounds?

I understand that data can be loaded using the Javascript console or through Hadoop command line but I am specifically looking at achieving this through code.

I went through some forums and found out that Hive connection right now requires you to have an azure storage account whether you have are using HDInsight Azure Service or not. Is this the case with loading data into HDFS too?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. A C library is provided with HDInsight for HDFS filesystem operations. See this [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Hadoop-Net-HDFS-File-Access-18e9bbee) for details and this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlnol/archive/2013/02/08/hdinsight-net-hdfs-file-access.aspx) for working examples.

Hope this helps.